# Inductively constructing a homeomorphism between CW complex and polyhedron

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

This is 5-18b of J. Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds".
Suppose $X$ is a regular CW complex. Then let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of open cells of $X$, $\mathcal{K}$ the collection of all nonempty finite subsets $\{e_0,...,e_k\}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ with the property that the dimensions of the elements are all distinct, and $e_{i-1}\subseteq\partial e_i$. I have shown that $\mathcal{K}$ is an abstract simplicial complex in part a) of the question. Part b) proceeds as follows:
Suppose $K$ is a Euclidean simplicial complex whose vertex scheme is isomorphic to $\mathcal{K}$. Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $|K|$ (the polyhedron of $K$) via a homeomorphism that sends the closure of each cell of $X$ onto the polyhedron of a subcomplex of $K$.
The reader is given the following hint: begin by choosing $v_e$ in each simplex $e\in\mathcal{E}$. Then define a homeomorphism inductively, one skeleton at a time, in such a way that it sends each point $v_e$ to the vertex of $K$ corresponding to $e$.

In previous exercises, I proved that any homeomorphism $f:\partial D\to\partial D'$ can be extended to a homeomorphism $F:D\to D'$, for two closed cells $D$ and $D'$. I understand that this fact should help me construct the homeomorphism in some inductive fashion, but I am not sure how to realise this construction. For the $0$-skeletons, it seems clear that the map should take every $e_0$ to $\{e_0
\}$. Then, assume the homeomorphism has been constructed for the $(n-1)$-skeleton. Denoting by $|K|_i$ the $i$-skeleton of the polyhedron $|K|$, we have a homeomorphism $F_{n-1}:X_{n-1}\to |K|_{n-1}$. From this, how would I create the homeomorphism for the $n$-skeleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That earlier exercise is not going to be sufficient, because your description of the induction has a flaw.

As you say, the homeomorphism between $X$ and $|K|$ is being constructed inductively on the skeleta $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots$. However, your induction hypothesis is incorrect, because the image $f(X_n)$ is not going to be equal to the entire $n$-skeleton of $|K|$; instead it is only going to be a subcomplex of the $n$-skeleton of $|K|$.

For example, $f(X_0)$ is not the entire $0$-skeleton of $|K|$, it is only the subcomplex of the $0$-skeleton corresponding to singleton sets $\{e_0\}$ such that the dimension of $e_0$ is equal to $0$.

More generally, given a cell $e \subset X$ of dimension $d \ge 1$ corresponding to a $0$-simplex $\{e\}$ of $|K|$, the point of $X$ which is mapped to that $0$-simplex by $f$ is going to be the chosen point $v_e$ in the interior of $e$. Thus the $0$-simplex $\{e\}$ is not contained in $f(X_{d-1})$, but it *is* contained in $f(X_d)$.

With that said, let me strengthen the hint from Lee's book somewhat. The description of $f$, *and* the induction hypothesis of the construction of $f$, should both state with more precision what is the image under $f$ of each closed cell in $X$:

- Given an open cell $e \subset X$, what will $f(\overline e) \subset |K|$ be?

If you can answer that question, you should be able to reformulate your induction and then proceed with the construction.

Comment: I have a question about your statement that $f(X_0)$ is not the entire $0$-skeleton. In the book, the definition of the $k$-skeleton of $K$ is the set of all simplices of $K$ with dimension at most $k$. What other simplices that aren't singleton sets with dimension $0$ does $|K|_0$ contain?

Comment: As said in my answer, those other sets are singleton sets $\{e\}$ with $\text{dimension}(e)\ge 1$.

Comment: Unless I've fully misunderstood the definition, aren't those prohibited from being in $|K|_0$ due to their dimension being greater than $0$? I apologise if this seems like a stupid question, but I must confess I find this subject rather confusing.

Comment: I think you may indeed have misunderstood the definition: "$\mathcal{K}$ the collection of all nonempty finite subsets $\{e_0,...,e_k\}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ with the property that the dimensions of the elements are all distinct, and $e_{i-1}\subseteq\partial e_i$." Other than requiring that the natural numbers $\text{dimension}(e_0),...,\text{dimension}(e_k)$ are all distinct, there is no other requirement on those natural numbers.

Comment: So, for example, in the case $k=0$, which is a singleton subset $\{e_0\} \subset \mathcal E$, there is no requirement whatsoever, **any** singleton subset of $\mathcal E$ is an element of the abstract simplicial complex $\mathcal K$.

Comment: What it looks like to me is that you have some confusions arising in the relations between the "abstract" simplicial complex $\mathcal K$, and the Euclidean simplicial complex whose vertex scheme is isomorphic to $\mathcal K$.

Comment: An important example to study is the case where $X$ is already a simplicial complex to begin with. In that case, $K$ turns out to be the first barycentric subdivision of $X$, with one $0$-simplex of $K$ for every simplex of $X$ (without any restriction on dimension).